# Can I replace my Trane XR13 AC condenser motor with a comparable motor?

Tags: hvac, motor

I have a Trane XR13 AC Condenser.  The motor started running really loud, and then the fan blade came off the shaft.  I put the blade back on the shaft twice... making sure to really tighten it the second time it came off.  Eventually the motor stopped running, although I can manually spin the blade without issue.

I want to change out the motor, the capacitor and the blade (I am not sure if the blade was damaged when it detached from the shaft, and I don't know if that will degrade efficiency or cause issues with the motor.)

The original motor has the following specs on the nameplate: HP: 1/5, RPM: 850 (service Facts that came in the manual say 835 RPM), V: 200/230, Cap: 7.5, Hz:60.  The blade is 27.6 diameter - 2 blade.

The closest matches I can find online are HP: 1/4 RPM: 825 and HP: 1/5 RPM: 825.

My question is, can I replace the original motor with the 1/4 - 825rpm or the 1/5 - 825rpm without causing any issues, such as loss of efficiency, or problems with the draw on the system?

Comment: Have you contacted Trane to get an exact match?

Comment: Was planning to call tomorrow. I figured getting it direct from Trane would cost more so I was trying to research on my own.

Comment: Did you check local AC  parts supply companies or where you searching the internet?

Comment: There should be a frame # on the motor tag the frame can be used to figure out all the psychical aspects of the motor , that with the rpm , Hp and voltage we should be able to get an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ed Beal wrote, check the frame number so that the physical size is the same as well as other specs he mentioned. You can buy a motor of the same HP or more but not any less, so a 1/4 HP will work. As far as the fan blade, I would consult Trane for the exact replacement so the unit moves the same amount of condensing air. After market blades may not match the air moving capabilities.

Comment: Trane customer service wasn't any help since I am not a technician or dealer.  I did find a local industrial supply company and called their support. A technician helped me find a commercial grade motor that matches what I need and will weather the North Texas heat better than the residential grade. I found another online supply company to order the blade. When I have all of the parts together I will post the details in case anyone else needs assistance. Thank you all for the responses.